# how to recursively list files from a folder?

Tags: linux

'ls dir1/**/*.ext' just lists all the files with just one level of nesting. What is the command to recursively list all the files with any level of nesting in linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls -R dir1
```

Or:

```
find dir1 -name "*.ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command is one way to do this:

```
find dir1 -name .ext
```

The `-name` operator *can* take a wildcard to match with, but it's important to quote the wildcard expression so that it won't be expanded by your shell before calling into `find`:

```
find dir1 -name "*.ext"
```

The `find` command has many operators that can do various different tests on the files in the directory, of which `-name` is just one example. Consult [the `find` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To list folder recursively:

```
ls -R
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find`:

```
find .
```

That command would list everything under the current folder