# Linux - Recursively list all files from folder with performance

Tags: linux, symlink, nas

I want to list down absolute filenames of almost 80 thousand files recursively from folders in text file.

Do anybody know which command will give me performance? 
I know that I can use commands like `ls`, `tree`, `ll` But which command will give me more performance.

Also note that these files are on NAS and NAS is mapped using `symlink` command.

Comment: You can do a benchmark when testing these options : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686514/how-to-recursively-list-files-from-a-folder

Comment: I'd say the performance of listing files primary depends on the hardware, since it is a read only operation. In case of a remote connection maybe additional the network latency for roundtrips.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `find -type f -print0` for zero-delimited output. I don't think you can get significantly faster than that.